# Xamarin.Forms: App does not show elements on the page

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, execution

I am currently learning to use Xamarin.Forms and C# (first week into it) and am trying to create a basic login app.
I started with a blank template. Now, when I run my app, only the basic screen pops up, but not the elements in the page. What is wrong?

App.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinApp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            new LoginPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

---

LoginPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinApp.LoginPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label 
                Text="Welcome"
                />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

---

LoginPage.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinApp
{
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing `new LoginPage();` to `this.MainPage = new LoginPage();`

Comment: @Bijington, what kind of sorcery is that? What was wrong with my code? Also, I do not have a MainPage.xaml in my code. Why do I still need to use `this.MainPage`?

Comment: you need to define what the starting page is. `MainPage` is a property of `App` I suspect there may already be something in your `App.xaml` file that points to a page.

Comment: @Bijington, [this](https://dpaste.com/3Q6V78ZH7) is my App.xaml

Comment: `new LoginPage();` just creates a new instance of a page in memory.  If you don't assign it to anything then it will just sit in memory until the GC cleans it up.  This is true of any C# object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL-DR**

I believe that to solve your problem you will need to change your line:

```
new LoginPage();
```

to:

```
MainPage = new LoginPage();
```

**My reasoning**

You need to specify what the `MainPage` is. This part can be seen as confusing when you first start out because the example page that is supplied is also called `MainPage` but one is a `class/Page` implementation and the other key part is a property provided by the `Application` class that your `App` class inherits from. So that the app when running knows it's starting `Page`.

Typically when you create a new Blank Xamarin.Forms app you will see the following code in App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new MainPage();
}
```

I suspect that your changes to add in your LoginPage somehow ended up removing the key part: `MainPage =` from that line.

Comment: I still don't get what `MainPage = new MainPage()` does. It looks like `System.Int32 = new System.Int32()`, or `classname = new classname()`. Shouldn't it be `MainPage mainPage = new MainPage()`?

Comment: Yes frustratingly for the purpose of this question the class and property have the same name. `MainPage` on the left is in fact a property and not a type. It is provided for you by the `Application` class provided by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.mainpage?view=xamarin-forms